# Default files in "/etc/ssh/" folder?

Tags: networking, ssh

I somehow managed to delete all the files in "/etc/ssh/" folder, I know I'm missing at least "/etc/ssh/ssh_config" and maybething else. Therefor I'm not able to connect to my PI through putty anymore.

I was manage to create new

/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

Keys, can anyone provide me default config files that belong there?

Reinstalling ssh from command line didn't create then new ones automatically for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to purge your installation first:

`sudo apt-get purge ssh`

And then reinstall, it should recreate configuration files.

Comment: Unfortunately purge and then reinstallation didn't work, it still didn't create the new config files.
I am able to connect to machine through ftp (I have vftps setup) but when I connect with xming I get connection refused, I'm pretty sure because the conf on my raspberry is missing... is there anyway to download the default conf files from the repo? I imagine they should be generic, at least in the beginning.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me ssh_config and sshd_config files (I believe they are the 2 needed besides keys), it would save me a lot of time compared to reinstalling everything.